# цикл for, шаблонизатор twig

Tags: php

Пытаюсь вывести список таблиц из БД.

После запроса, массив имеет такой вид

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_createtable] => car
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_createtable] => job
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_createtable] => jobs
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Tables_in_createtable] => web
        )

)
```

Потом передаю этот массив для шаблона в twig, но почему-то ничего не выводит

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'createtable';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host; dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$showTables = "SHOW TABLES";
$show = $pdo->prepare($showTables);
$show->execute();
$res = $show->fetchAll(); //массив со списком таблиц

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => 'cache'
));

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('hello.twig');
$template->display($res);
```

А вот код твига

```
<html>
<body>

    <ul>
    {% for table in tab %}
        <li>{{table.Tables_in_createtable}}</li>
    {% endfor %}    
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: не вижу связи между `res` в логике и `tables` в предсталвении, `$template->display(['tab' => $res])` мб ?

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, как вывести этот список, с помощью твига